# How to pass variables from Github actions to docker-compose and into appsettings.json

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I have been trying to pass my variables from my Github secrets to my docker-compose into my appsettings.json file. However, when I pushed it onto Github to start building the images and then downloaded the images from my server, i noticed that my appsettings is still empty.

Here is my docker-compose for my api:

```
sdr_app.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT=Docker_Dev_DO
      - TZ=Asia/Singapore
      - SDR__APP__API__APPLICATION__ID=$${{ secrets.DEV_SDR_APP_API_APPLICATION_ID }}
      - BASE__LINK=$${{ secrets.DEV_BASE_LINK }}
      - APPLICATION__STORAGE=$${{ secrets.DEV_APPLICATION_STORAGE }}
      - CULTURE=$${{ secrets.DEV_CULTURE }}
      - FILE__CACHE__IN__SECONDS=$${{ secrets.DEV_FILE_CACHE_IN_SECONDS }}
      - DEPLOY__ORIGIN=$${{ secrets.DEV_DEPLOY_ORIGIN }}
    image: ghcr.io/<user>/sdr_app.api:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SDR_App.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - ${NETWORK}
    volumes:
    - "../appo/:/app-volumes/"
    - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

Here is my appsettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error"
    }
  },
  "SDR_APP_CONNECTIONSTRING": "",

  "BASE_LINK": "",


  "APPLICATION_STORAGE": "",

  "CULTURE": "",
  "FILE_CACHE_IN_SECONDS": "",

  "DEPLOY_ORIGIN": "",

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

After deployment, i checked my appsettings and its still empty. What else am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would "your server" have access to github secrets?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I build the image via Github Actions and then ssh into my server. So the secrets come from Github Actions

Comment: Does this even work without Github actions and setting env vars with just `docker run -e`? Your appsettings have only one underscore, but your environment variables have two?

Comment: Github secrets are (probably) lost as soon as you SSH.

Comment: I read that I needed to use double underscores to pass the environment variables from docker-compose

Comment: Where did you read that? Two underscores  don't mean anything for compose environment variables... Asp.net may need it, though, but that has nothing to do with Docker

Comment: I actually build the image, store the image onto Github packages and then download it from my server. I've edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll try to change it back to 1 underscore to see if it can be passed through. Do I need to remove the 2 $$ into 1 as well?

Comment: Are you running `ssh -c "docker compose up"`? If so, there's no Github secrets passed through that connection to external systems... If that were possible, then it would  leak credentials to any external systems

Comment: Oh! I understand now. That means I have to do it in my Dockerfile instead as its being built inside Github.

Comment: Secrets should not be added to Dockerfile, as those would be exposed as plaintext with `docker history` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github secrets should only be used for building, not running the image.

If you're using Docker Compose on your server, you can create a `.env` file with your runtime secrets.

If you are using self-hosted Kubernetes/Nomad, you can look into other secrets management solutions such as Hashicorp Vault. Otherwise, most cloud providers have their own secrets management solutions